# How to fix Flutter Firebase app doesn't exit error 6904

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect my Flutter app with Firebase but it shows lots of error I don't know what is wrong. In this basically I am pressing the flat button to connect using firbase_auth and create a user.

I am using AndroidX and installed packages and also tried flutter clean, but nothing works, I followed all instructions in firebase to register my app for android and also multiDexEnabled to true in app level build.gradle

My code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ConnectionPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
        title: Text("Connection Page"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("Button"), 
            onPressed: () async {
              final userInfo = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: "vishnu@email.com", password: "1234");
              print(userInfo.user);
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is pubspec.yaml

```
name: stockexchange
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.0
  google_fonts: ^0.3.10
  charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/

  fonts:
    - family: CustomIcon
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CustomIcon.ttf
```

and this the error I am having after running and typing

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:218)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.getAuth(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:129)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:143)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 6904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter ( 6904): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. , null)
E/flutter ( 6904): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter ( 6904): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6904): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349:48)
E/flutter ( 6904): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:64:23)
E/flutter ( 6904): #4      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:64:10)
E/flutter ( 6904): #5      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45:6)
E/flutter ( 6904): #6      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:57:52)
E/flutter ( 6904): #7      ConnectionPage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:stockexchange/pages/connection_spec_page.dart:42:46)
E/flutter ( 6904): #8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45:6)
E/flutter ( 6904): #9      ConnectionPage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:stockexchange/pages/connection_spec_page.dart:38:30)
E/flutter ( 6904): #10     InputBoardState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:stockexchange/components/input_board.dart:110:24)
E/flutter ( 6904): #11     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter ( 6904): #12     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter ( 6904): #13     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 6904): #14     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter ( 6904): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter ( 6904): #16     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #17     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter ( 6904): #18     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 6904): #19     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter ( 6904): #20     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 6904): #21     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter ( 6904): #22     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #23     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 6904): #24     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 6904): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #26     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #27     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #28     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter ( 6904): #29     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter ( 6904): #30     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter ( 6904): #31     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter ( 6904): #32     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter ( 6904):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you skip some of the necessary steps to hook up your Flutter app to Firebase. You not only have to place google-service.json file into your android/app directory, but you also have to edit two build.gradle files.

I would recommend you make sure to follow each and every step in the official documentation below:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup